# How do I create a cursor for a linked list text editor in Python?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have an assignment where I have to convert text into nodes for a doubly-linked list and print it. I also have to make an underline cursor and do the following:

Move the cursor left one character (do nothing if at the beginning).
Move the cursor right one character (do nothing if at the end).
Insert a new character after the cursor.
Delete a character after the cursor (do nothing at the end).

The biggest issue is creating the cursor and moving it back and forth. I've been trying to create methods that can move the underline around when I call them, but nothing I try works.
Here's a copy of what I have so far.

```
class _DoublyLinkedBase:
    class _Node:
        __slots__ = '_element', '_prev', '_next',

        def __init__(self, element, prev, next):
            self._element = element
            self._prev = prev
            self._next = next


    def __init__(self):
        self._header = self._Node(None, None, None)
        self._trailer = self._Node(None, None, None)
        self._header._next = self._trailer
        self._trailer._prev = self._header
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0

    def _insert_between(self, e, predecessor, successor):
        newest = self._Node(e, predecessor, successor)
        predecessor._next = newest
        successor._prev = newest
        self._size += 1
        return newest

    def _delete_node(self, node):
        predecessor = node._prev
        successor = node._next
        predecessor._next = successor
        successor._prev = predecessor
        self._size -= 1
        element = node._element
        node._prev = node._next = node._element = None
        return element


class PositionalList(_DoublyLinkedBase):
    class Position:
        def __init__(self, container, node):
            self._container = container
            self._node = node

        def current(self):
            move_cursor = self._node
            return move_cursor

        def element(self):
            return self._node._element

        def __eq__(self, other):
            return type(other) is type(self) and other._node is self._node

        def __ne__(self, other):
            return not (self == other)

    def _validate(self, p):
        if not isinstance(p, self.Position):
            raise TypeError('p must be proper Position type')
        if p._container is not self:
            raise ValueError('p does not belong to this container')
        if p._node._next is None and p._node._prev is None:
            raise ValueError('p is no longer valid')
        return p._node

    def _make_position(self, node):
        if node is self._header or node is self._trailer:
            return None
        else:
            return self.Position(self, node)

    def first(self):
        return self._make_position(self._header._next)

    def last(self):
        return self._make_position(self._trailer._prev)

    def before(self, p):
        node = self._validate(p)
        return self._make_position(node._prev)

    def after(self, p):
        node = self._validate(p)
        return self._make_position(node._next)

    def current(self, p):
        node = self._validate(p)
        return self._make_position(node._element)

    def _insert_between(self, e, predecessor, successor):
        node = super()._insert_between(e, predecessor, successor)
        return self._make_position(node)

    def add_first(self, e):
        return self._insert_between(e, self._header, self._header._next)

    def add_last(self, e):
        return self._insert_between(e, self._trailer._prev, self._trailer)

    def add_before(self, p, e):
        original = self._validate(p)
        return self._insert_between(e, original._prev, original)

    def add_after(self, p, e):
        original = self._validate(p)
        return self._insert_between(e, original, original._next)

    def delete(self, p):
        original = self._validate(p)
        return self._delete_node(original)

    def replace(self, p, e):
        original = self._validate(p)
        old_value = original._element
        original._element = e
        return old_value

    def __iter__(self):
        cursor = newList.first()
        while cursor is not None:
            print(cursor.element(), end="")
            cursor = newList.after(cursor)
        return cursor

    def cursor_left(self):
        cursor = newList.last()
        newList.replace(cursor, "\u0332".join(cursor.element()))
        cursor = newList.before(cursor)

    #def cursor_right(self, cursor):


def print_init():
    for i in range(len(text)):
        newList.add_last(text[i])
    newList.add_last(" " + "\u0332")
    newList.__iter__()



newList = PositionalList()
text = "Type what you like here."
print_init()
```

Comment: *"...but nothing I try works"*: please focus on **one** problem, and clearly state for which input you get into the problem, what the behaviour is (error? wrong output? hanging?) and what you expect instead. Also limit the code to only the necessary parts that are needed to reproduce the problem. Don't include methods/classes that are unrelated to the problem.

Comment: My bad. I'll narrow it down, then. My problem is the cursor_left method near the bottom. It's supposed to move my cursor by replacing the element in the previous node with an underlined copy of that same element. That's the part I haven't been able to successfully complete.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. Please edit your question.